# Synchronize my music between my PC and the microsd on my Lg L70 ms323

Tags: 14.04, android, sync, banshee, lg

I have a rooted Lg L70 ms323 with android 4.4.2 I want to sync my music in my microsd. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Banshee player sync puts the music on the root of my phone internal memory.

I read that one should create a .is_audio_player file for Banshee sync process. I have tried putting the .is_audio_player (More info below) either on the internal memory and the microsd with no result.

This is the `.is_audio_player` content:

```
name="BatPhone"
audio_folders= Music/
folder_depth=2
output_formats=audio/mpeg,audio/x-ms-wma,application/ogg
playlist_formats=audio/x-mpegurl,audio/mpeg-url
playlist_path=Playlists/

endoffile=PlaceThisHereToEnsureThereIsABlankSpaceBeforeTheLastLineOfTheFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

## Create a folder for mounting

```
mkdir -p ~/android.devices/
```

## Unmount any device

```
fusermount -u /home/`whoami`/android.devices
```

## Mount 1st mtp device found

```
jmtpfs ~/android.devices/
```

## Sync content

```
rsync -rtvuc --delete --progress /home/`whoami`/android.devices/SD\ card/Music /home/`whoami`/Music
```

## Unmount device

```
fusermount -u /home/`whoami`/android.devices
```